# How do i solve this limit? It's about $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ and $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = 0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$ and $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = 0$$

I can't come up with any solution. Could you please help me?

Also: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}$$

Comment: @amWhy Why did you rollback to the improper $\LaTeX$? :o

Comment: Because you left out part of the OP's post.

Comment: @amWhy Oh, oops, thanks for the fix!

Comment: @user111382 : You shouldn't write $1-\cos(x)/x$ if you mean $(1-\cos(x))/x$.  Those are different.

Comment: @Ahaan Your formatting was fine...better than my initial formatting! I just wanted to quickly complete the post.

Comment: @amWhy You did so rightly. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{\tan x\sin x}=\frac{(1-\cos^2x)\cos x}{(1+\cos x)\sin^2x}=\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}$$ if $\sin x\ne0$

Here as $x\to0\implies x\ne0\implies\sin x\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

write down the definition of the derivative (i.e. the difference quotient $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$) for

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\vert_{x=0}\sin(x)
$$

and
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\vert_{x=0}\cos(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x) = x$ for small values of $x$; i.e. $\sin(x)$ and $x$ have the same evolution. So $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}1=1$$

[image]